# Extract hour from a date time string

Tags: javascript

I have a date time string that looks like this:

```
Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

I need to get the hour from the string so I can use it in a variable.

For example the result I'm looking for on the above string would be: `07`

How can I do this?

Comment: `new Date(string).getHours()`

Comment: Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/bgcpkq3s/ It will be 24-hour time, with a value from 0-23 so you have to add +1 for hour

Comment: @Manoj, you do not "fix" 24 hour time by adding an hour to it. 0 is midnight, which is either 0:00 or 12:00 AM. 1 is 1:00 or 1:00 AM, 2 is 2:00, etc. Adding one does not help!

Comment: @urhen, you've made a mistake by accepting the "subtract 1" answer as THE answer to your question. It's a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the answer above, something like:

`new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)").getHours()`

...will return the hours portion of a date, but there are three important things to be aware of:

1. This will be the hours in *your system's current time zone*, not necessary the time zone the date was given in. (There's also an alternative method, `getUTCHours()`, that always returns hours for UTC.)
2. It will be a number, not a string with a leading 0 when less than 10.
3. It will be 24-hour time, with a value from 0-23, not AM/PM, if that's what you're looking for.

If you'd always want to get the hour as provided in the original date, parsing the hour from the date with a regex would be a better idea. What that regex would look like, however, would depend on how flexible you need to be with the variety of original date/time formats.

For even more flexibility, you could parse the date/time starting like this:

```
const dateStr = 'Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)';
const date = new Date(dateStr);`
```

...then also parse out the original hour offset given:

```
const parts = /(?:GMT|UTC)([-+])(\d\d)(\d\d)/.exec(dateStr);
const offsetMinutes = parts ? (parseInt(parts[2]) * 60 + parseInt(parts[3])) * (parts[1] === '-' ? -1 : 1) : 0;
```

Then, with a bit more work, convert to any time zone offset you like.

Please be aware that time zone offsets are not always in whole hours, so there could be two different hours in one timezone that match one hour in another timezone, depending on the minutes which go along with the hour.

Oh, one more thing...

Using this regex:

`/[T ](\d{1,2}):/.exec(dateStr)[1]` (there's a space after the `T`)

...will pretty reliably extract the hour, as originally given, from a wide variety of date/time strings. The code above is written as if the regex won't fail. Break it up into testing that `/[T ](\d{1,2}):/.exec(dateStr)` isn't `null` before extracting the hour with `[1]` for more reliable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var d = new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
   console.log(d.getHours());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Date object from the string and then extract the hours from that.

```
var date = new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)");
var hours = date.getHours(); // -> 8
// If you want a leading zero for 1 digit hours
if(hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours; // -> "08"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be exact with the hours **string**, this would handle it:

`new Date().getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');`

It will:

1) fetch the hours as a number (single digit when < 10)

2) convert it to string

3) add leading zero when less than 10

Answer (score 0):

**It will be 24-hour time, with a value from 0-23 so we have to add +1**

```js
       var d = new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
    let hourtime=document.getElementById('hourtime');
    hourtime.innerHTML=d.getUTCHours()+1
```

```html
<strong id="hourtime"></strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

In es6,

```
 const MyDate = new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
```

to construct a date object with given time  and now to get the hours jus to

```
console.log(MyDate.getHours());
```

Answer (score -1):

@onik's code looks fine but this returns hour + 1 for some reason

```js
var hour = new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
console.log(hour.getHours());


// returns hour + 1 for some reason
```

rather do this

```js
var hour = new Date("Thu Aug 15 2019 07:15:03 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
console.log(hour.getHours() - 1);
```

Run snippets below and see for yourself

Comment: It's not a good idea to depend on simply subtracting one fixed hour. This is a matter of local time zone vs. original time zone (see my complete answer). Any adjustment that might be needed can vary greatly.

Comment: i agree, this was a quick workaround to @oniks answer down below. i did not investigate as to why hours returns 8 instead of 7.